# IBM Cloudant '413 Request Entity Too Large' on document creation

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I'm trying to create a document from IBM Cloudant service in BlueMix. The size of this document is in excess of 10mb. Now every time I try to create this document it throws an error saying, '413 Request Entity Too Large'.

I've tried creating documents of similar size in past but never had any problems. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Max doc size is limited to 1M on Bluemix Public Standard and Lite plans.